# A counterexample to a statement of Grothendieck and Verdier?

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory, set-theory

In [the first Exposé of SGA4](http://www.normalesup.org/~forgogozo/SGA4/01/01.pdf), right after Definition 2.1, we read

(1) For variable $G,\ \varprojlim G$ is a functor from the category $\text{Funct}(I,\mathcal C)$ to $\widehat{\mathcal C}$.

(In French: "Pour $G$ variable, $\varprojlim G$ est un foncteur de la catégorie $\text{Fonct}(I,\mathcal C)$ à valeurs dans $\widehat{\mathcal C}$.")

Recall that $\mathcal U$ is a nonempty universe, $\mathcal C$ a $\mathcal U$-category, $X$ an object of $\mathcal C$, $I$ a $\mathcal U$-small category, and $\varprojlim G$ is defined by
$$
\left(\varprojlim G\right)(X):=\text{Hom}_{\text{Funct}(I,\mathcal C)}(k_X,G).
$$ 
To find a counterexample to (1) it suffices to find a triple $(\mathcal U,\mathcal C,X)$ where $\mathcal U$ is a universe, $\mathcal C$ a $\mathcal U$-small category and $X$ an object of $\mathcal C$ such that

(2) $\text{End}_{\text{Funct}(\mathcal C,\mathcal C)}(k_X)\notin\mathcal U$.

It seems to me the following provides such a counterexample.

Let $\mathcal U$ be a nonempty universe and $X$ a set such that

(3) $X\notin\mathcal U$,

and define the category $\mathcal C$ by
$$
\text{Ob}(\mathcal C) :=\{X\}=:\text{End}_{\mathcal C}(X).
$$

We have
$$
\text{id}_{k_X}\in\text{End}_{\text{Funct}(\mathcal C,\mathcal C)}(k_X)\subset\prod_{Y\in\{X\}}\text{End}_{\mathcal C}(X)
$$ 
$$
=\prod_{Y\in\{X\}}\{X\}= \{\{(X,X)\}\} 
$$
and thus

(4) $\text{End}_{\text{Funct}(\mathcal C,\mathcal C)}(k_X)=\{\{(X,X)\}\}$.

Here is a general observation:

(5) For any set $Y$ we have $Y\in\mathcal U$ if and only if there is a chain 
$$
Y=Y_0\in Y_1\in\cdots\in Y_n=\mathcal U
$$ 
with $n\ge1$.

Now (2) follows from (3), (4) and (5).

What am I missing?

Comment: But if $X\notin \mathcal{U}$, then $\{X\}\notin \mathcal{U}$, so $\mathcal{C}$ is not $\mathcal{U}$-small, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @AlexKruckman - The terminology is explained in Section 1.0 of the linked Exposé. A category is $\mathcal U$-small if its set of morphisms is *equipotent* (*not* equal) to some $S\in\mathcal U$. Thanks for your interest!

Comment: Oh! I'm surprised to see that definition in SGA. My impression was always that one of the benefits of using universes is that while the category of $\mathcal{U}$-small categories (or $\mathcal{U}$-small sets, groups, etc.) is not $\mathcal{U}$-small, it is $\mathcal{U}'$-small for some larger universe $\mathcal{U}'$. And this is the case if $\mathcal{U}$-small means "is an element of $\mathcal{U}$". If it means "is isomorphic to an element of $\mathcal{U}$", then the category of $\mathcal{U}$-small categories can never be small in any universe.

Comment: @AlexKruckman - In SGA4 there 3 notions of smallness for a category $\mathcal C$ with respect to a universe $\mathcal U$. By increasing strength: $\mathcal C$ is a $\mathcal U$-category, $\mathcal C$ is $\mathcal U$-small, $\mathcal C\in\mathcal U$. The categories $\mathcal C$ such that $\mathcal C\in\mathcal U$ do form a category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is indeed a problem with that definition.

An easy way to fix it is to define $\varprojlim G$ instead as the presheaf
$$X \longmapsto h_{\mathcal U}(G)(k_X)$$
where $h_{\mathcal U}(G)$ is defined as in the Construction-Definition 1.3. Notice that
$$h_{\mathcal U}(G)(k_X) = \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Funct}(I, \mathcal C)}(k_X, G)$$
whenever the hom-set is a $\mathcal U$-set, so the definition morally agrees with the given one. But now, in your counterexample we have that
$$\left (\varprojlim k_X \right)(X) = h_{\mathcal U}(k_X)(k_X) = \tau_Z R(Z)$$
where $R(Z, X)$ is the relation "$Z$ is the target of an isomorphism $\mathrm{End}_{\mathrm{Funct}(\mathcal C, \mathcal C)}(k_X) \xrightarrow{\sim} Z$", and so by axiom $(\mathcal U\, B)$ it follows that $\left (\varprojlim k_X \right )(X) \in \mathcal U$ (because clearly there exists a $Z \in \mathcal U$ such that $\{ \{ (X, X) \} \} \simeq Z$, even if $X \notin \mathcal U$).

Comment: Thanks! +1. I think that your answer is correct, and that your fix is perfectly in the spirit of the Exposé. I prefer to wait a bit before accepting the answer to see if other users have other things to say.

Comment: I'd be delighted to have your opinion about this question https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2607963/660