# About the definition of a presheaf in SGA4

Tags: proof-verification, category-theory, set-theory

This is a follow up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2600889/660).

In view of [Luca Bressan's answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2601358/660) it seems that Definition 2.1 in [the first Exposé of SGA4](http://www.normalesup.org/~forgogozo/SGA4/01/01.pdf) doesn't really make sense as stated. Luca Bressan found a fix which, I think, is probably the one that Grothendieck and Verdier would have given if the problem had been pointed out to them. There is, however, a putative fix which is much simpler, and indeed so simple that I suspect there is a catch. But I haven't been able to find this catch. So, I will describe the putative fix and ask the reader to tell me what's wrong with it.

First of all, to avoid any misunderstanding, let me spell out an important assumption which is implicit in the Exposé: categories have, by definition, disjoint hom-sets.

For any universe $\mathcal U$ and $\mathcal V$ such that $\mathcal{U\subset V}$ write $i_{\mathcal{VU}}$ for the inclusion of $\mathcal U\text{-Set}$ into $\mathcal V\text{-Set}$.

The basic principle can be summarized as follows. In order to develop category theory we have to make lots of choices of universe, but we want of course our end results to be independent of these choices.

The following construction turns out to be a crucial tool. To a category $\mathcal C$ and a universe $\mathcal U$ we attach the category $\widehat{\mathcal C}_{\mathcal U}$ of functors $F:\mathcal C^{\text{op}}\to\mathcal U\text{-Set}$, such functors being called $\mathcal U$-Set *valued presheaves over* $\mathcal C$, or just *presheaves*.

Let $F\in\widehat{\mathcal C}_{\mathcal U}$ and $G\in\widehat{\mathcal C}_{\mathcal V}$. We consider $F$ and $G$ to be "essentially equal" if $F(X)=G(X)$ for all $X$ in $\mathcal C$, or, equivalently, if there is a universe $\mathcal W$ such that $\mathcal W\supset\mathcal U,\mathcal V$ and $i_{\mathcal{WU}}\circ F=i_{\mathcal{WV}}\circ G$. In some sense we are interested in presheaves mainly up to "essential equality". This means that there is no harm in replacing the universe we are working with by a larger one.

In the beginning of [the first Exposé of SGA4](http://www.normalesup.org/~forgogozo/SGA4/01/01.pdf) the authors attach

$\bullet$ a presheaf $h_{\mathcal U}(X)$ to an object $X$ of a category $\mathcal C$ and

$\bullet$ a presheaf $\varprojlim^{\mathcal U}G$ to a functor $G:I\to\mathcal C$

by choosing a certain universe $\mathcal U$, the constraint being of course that these presheaves should be well defined up to "essential equality".

Grothendieck and Verdier choose a universe $\mathcal U$ which has the property

$(P(\mathcal U))$: for all objects $X$ and $Y$ of $\mathcal C$, the set $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X,Y)$ is equipotent to some element of $\mathcal U$.

We suggest to consider the stronger property

$(Q(\mathcal U))$: $\mathcal C\in\mathcal U$.

Note that $(P(\mathcal U))$ and $\mathcal U\subset\mathcal V$ imply $(P(\mathcal V))$, and similarly for $Q$.

My suggestion is to replace property $P$ with property $Q$.

If we do this, we don't need Axiom $(\mathcal U\ B)$, which is stated in the language of Bourbaki's set theory, and whose translation in the ZFC language is not obvious to me. Moreover, in "Construction-définition 1.3", we can define $h_{\mathcal U}(x)(y)$ as being $\text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(y,x)$ is all cases. Finally, the definition of the projective limit of a functor $G:I\to\mathcal C$ given in Definition 2.1 of the Exposé becomes correct, even without Luca Bressan's fix. (We assume $I\in\mathcal U$ instead of "$I$ is $\mathcal U$-small"; any $\mathcal U$-small category being isomorphic to some category $\in\mathcal U$, we don't really lose generality. Note that the fact that $\varprojlim^{\mathcal U}G$ well defined up to "essential equality" is not stated explicitly by Grothendieck and Verdier.)

What's wrong with this approach?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want $(Q(\mathcal U))$ to be the property "$\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X, Y) \in \mathcal U$ for all objects $X$ and $Y$ of $\mathcal C$" instead? As you stated it, $(Q(\mathcal U))$ is _much_ stronger than $(P(\mathcal U))$, because it implies that $\mathcal C$ is $\mathcal U$-small, not just that $\mathcal C$ is a $\mathcal U$-category.

Comment: I don't want to pretend to understand these definitions, but from the little I understand, this is practically trivial when you consider that a universe is just some $V_\alpha$, and is therefore trivially closed under most things you might want it to be closed. But hey, what do I know about these things... :)?

Comment: @LucaBressan - It seems to me that, the hom-sets being disjoint, "$\text{Hom}_{\mathcal C}(X,Y)\in \mathcal U$ for all objects $X$ and $Y$ of $\mathcal C$" implies $\mathcal C\in\mathcal U$. At any rate, the idea is that, since we want things to be compatible with universe, there is no harm in choosing much much bigger universes.

Comment: The weaker version of $(Q(\mathcal U))$ proposed by @LucaBressan may well suffice for the purposes of SGA4, and that might (despite the length of SGA4) not be too difficult to check. Nevertheless, I'd be inclined to use the version of $(Q(\mathcal U))$ in the question. It may require the use of an unnecessarily large universe, but, as far as I know, SGA4 cares only about what happens "in the limit" of larger & larger universes. My (perhaps oversimplified) view is that any $\mathcal C$ can be made small by some choice of universe, so I might as well make it small.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - The question only refers to the part of the Exposé from the beginning up Definition 2.1. I'm sure you that can understand this much better that I, and that, if you're interested, you can say valuable things about that, and might perhaps come up with a better idea.

Comment: Well, since I don't *really* know what is a sheaf, presheaf, or what truly is an inverse limit (despite having seen the definitions for *all* of these several times by now), I don't think that I can *actually* follow that definition... :)

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard That is not true (consider the category of $\mathcal U$-sets: the _objects_ all belong to $\mathcal U$, the _set of all objects_ does not). But anyway, I see your point. I guess that there is nothing inherently wrong with your approach, but it does break the principle of equivalence (as pointed out in the Remark 1.1.2 of the Exposé), i.e., if $\mathcal C$ is a $\mathcal U$-category (in the sense of your property $(Q(\mathcal U))$) and $\mathcal C$ is equivalent to $\mathcal D$, then $\mathcal D$ might not be a $\mathcal U$-category.

Comment: @LucaBressan - For the first point, you're right, thanks! I also agree with your second point, but I'd be tempted to think that the added technical simplicity compensates for the break you mention. Of course it's a matter of opinion.

Comment: @AsafKaragila - The Exposé doesn't assume you know these notions... (Even if I suspect you know more than you say.)

Comment: (Evidence so far is to the contrary, I probably know much less than I say... But I also say a lot, so it's not saying that I don't know nothing... :))

Comment: @LucaBressan - Your comment looks like an answer.

Comment: @AndreasBlass - Thanks! You say in a much clearer way what I tried to say in the question. You write "My (perhaps oversimplified) view is that any $\mathcal C$ can be made small by some choice of universe". A category (in SGA4) is a set, and any set is $\in\mathcal U$ for some universe $\mathcal U$ (Axiom $(\mathcal U\ A)$ at the beginning of the Exposé). Your comment looks also like an answer.

Comment: Concerning the axiom (UB): This just means that the (global) axiom of choice always chooses inside the smallest possible universe.